# Is the sum sin(n) bounded?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, real-analysis

I wonder whether the sequence $s_{n} = \sum_{k = 1}^{n} \sin k$ is bounded.

The answer seems no, but I have no idea how to prove this from the irrationality of $\pi$.

Comment: It's not a research level question. You should ask it at math.stack.exchange. 

Answer (score 11):

In this particular case, use $s_n(\theta)=\sum_{k=0}^n\sin(k\theta)=\Im(\sum_{k=0}^n\exp(ki\theta))=\dots=\frac{\sin(n\theta/2)\sin((n+1)\theta/2)}{\sin (\theta/2)}$

Comment: In particular, $s_n$ is bounded.